# while installing node.js getting permission denied error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I downloaded the file for version 8.9.2 of node js and I am using lubuntu. I extracted the tar.xz file of nodejs I downloaded into a folder I made, and then in my command line entered

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v8.9.2/node-v8.9.2.tar.gz
```

But then this shows up.

```
--2017-12-07 22:08:56--  http://nodejs.org/dist/v8.9.2/node-v8.9.2.tar.gz
Resolving nodejs.org (nodejs.org)... 2400:cb00:2048:1::6814:172e, 2400:cb00:2048:1::6814:162e, 104.20.22.46, ...
Connecting to nodejs.org (nodejs.org)|2400:cb00:2048:1::6814:172e|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 31109143 (30M) [application/gzip]
node-v8.9.2.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘node-v8.9.2.tar.gz’ (Permission denied).
```

So how do I install it properly?

Comment: This question would fit better on `https://askubuntu.com/`

Comment: You don't have write permissions in the `/usr/src` directory.

Answer (score 1):

As Kishor Pawar already mentionet:

The folder `/usr/src` belongs to the user root and your current user does not have write access (you can see that by using `ls -al /usr/src`)

In order to install it you have multiple Options:

1. use linux package-manager. 
   Install it via `sudo apt-get install package=version` ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/428778/335542))
2. use a wrapper like nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm)
3. installing it manually: the user that uses npm needs to have write access to all folder that are used by npm. So in case you want to install it to /usr/src  your user needs to be a sudoer. Else install it into your homefolder(i am not sure if this is sufficient)

Option 2 is my preferred option for a developing machine. You can easily install specific version and have them in parallel and switch versions as you need. Easy to use and easy to upgrade. No hassle on access privileges, as it puts all dependencies to the users home folder.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be `root` or have use `sudo` before command provided you are added to `sudoers` group.